# UIButton selector not called

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uibutton, event-listener

I have a UIButton inside a class. I want to set a target for the button like so.

```
[myController.dateButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

For some reason, the selector is never called when I press the button. I tried to debug the problem by doing the following but I get nil for the NSSet

```
NSSet *allTargets = [myController.dateButton allTargets];
```

Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong?

The selector is defined as follows:

```
- (void)showAction:(id)sender
{
   // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this be the solution, cz i dnt think there's anything wrong in your code.

When you declare your button as

```
UIButton* tempBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

never have the release called on that btn.

```
[tempBtn release];//dont do this!!
```

I tried this my selves and it was working fine.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     UIButton* tempBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
     tempBtn.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50);
     [tempBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(hello:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [self.view addSubview:tempBtn];

}

- (void) hello:(id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"helloooo");
}
```

Comment: It work fine for first time but not when this thing is in tableview cell and bind for second time...!?!